# Wildcard and has value on checkbox not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Sorry for my poorly worded question time for re edit.  When with text boxes I have the has value method for determining if a value is null or not and I can use the wildcard opertator as such as below

```
if (_currentiandEValues.STEP_CHANGE_SCHOOL_ACTIVTIES == 0)
 childpocketmoney.Value = Decimal.Round(_dal.getiandEData(_myuser.id, STEP_CHANGE_SCHOOL_ACTIVTIES"), 2);
else
{
  childpocketmoney.Value _currentiandEValues.STEP_CHANGE_SCHOOL_ACTIVTIES.HasValue ? Decimal.Round((decimal)_currentiandEValues.STEP_CHANGE_SCHOOL_ACTIVTIES, 2) : defaultvalue;
}
```

How would I do the same for the checkbox control as such I am getting a null error on this line

```
chkRedundancy.Checked = (bool) _record.redundancyRecieved;
```

Is it just a matter of doing but when i attempt the below i get the same error nullable object must have a value?

```
  chkRedundancy.Checked = (bool) _record.redundancyRecieved  ? true : fals;
```

So I need to be able to do the same above with the has value but for a check box.

**PS The value will only ever be true or false from the database so it will.**

But it appears to be incorrect syntax does any body have any tips on the wild card and checkboxes please both values are boolean by the way

**Error being got**

> [InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.]
>      System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource) +56
>      System.Nullable`1.get_Value() +2714906
>      portal.myaccount.ChangeInCircumstance.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects\dashboard6\portal\myaccount\ChangeInCircumstance.aspx.cs:679
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +109
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4498

Comment: Didn't understand the question to be honest. 
`chkRedundancy.Checked = _record.redundancyRecieved.HasValue ?` Looks like a compilation error as you started writing a ternary operator like `chkReducedHoursWork.Checked = _record.reducedHours.HasValue ? _record.reducedHours: false` and didn't complete it. :|

Comment: Please restate your question in a way that explains what you are trying to achieve. As-Is it is hard to tell.

Comment: @Tim sorry for my poorly formed question I have re editited the question

Answer (score 0):

.Checked expects boolean.

```
bool defaultvalue = false;
chkRedundancy.Checked = _record.redundancyRecieved.HasValue;
chkReducedHoursWork.Checked = _record.reducedHours.HasValue ? _record.reducedHours > 0: false;
```

Would be valid syntax, but without knowing what you are trying to acheive it is hard to know. ? is not a wildcard.

Comment: why would reduced hours be greater than zero when its a true or false resort sorry if my question was un clear I have since reedited the question and gave an error what I was getting

Answer (score 0):

It Appears all I have to do for the checkbox is the simliar statment and this gives me the desired result

```
chkRedundancy.Checked = (bool)_record.redundancyRecieved.HasValue ? true : false;
```